# Transport Pooling optimization based on pallet number

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization

I several clients that have orders planned for the same day, from the same shipping point to the same delivery point.
Each of their orders do not fill a truck, so I wish to pool their orders to optimize costs.

My goal is to be as close as I can to my maximum number of pallets per truck (which is 35).
The condition for a pooling to be valid, it has to contain an order of at least two different clients.

```
e.g.
[client1]-> nb of Pals (30, 10, 5, 20)
[client2]-> nb of Pals (10, 15, 30, 10, 11)
[client3]-> nb of Pals (10, 5, 2, 4)
 
Valid poolings would be
30 pals from client1 + 5 pals from client3
10  + 4 pals from client3 + 10 pals from client2 + 10 pals from client1
(...)
```

I've tried the following approach:

1. Sum the total of pals and divide by the nb of pals per truck to find the minimum number of poolings to contain all orders
2. Create the minimal number of poolings by putting in them the max pal of client i and the min pals of client i+1
3. Then try to allocate the remaining pals in the existing poolings. If they don't fit in any of them, I create a new pooling.

This solutions clearly is not optimal and does not always work (as of MAX(client1) + MIN(client2) = 40, which is > 35).

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance.

FYI I'm developing this in PHP

Comment: This sounds like a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Also, since there is not always possible to pool from different clients (e.g. client1: [25, 10], client2:[20, 15]) I would suggest to try to define a score for such cases too. E.g. try to minimize (number of pooled truck) + 2* (number of unpooled trucks)

Comment: I suspect there are two objectives: (1) minimize total number of truck loads (2) keep orders of clients together as much as possible. I.e. penalize "splitting" a client.

Comment: The goal is to indeed to minimize the number of trucks. For the orders that will not be pooled (and the pooling that will not have the optimal number of pallets, either too much or not enough) will go through a second round of negotitions. Clients will be notified to add or remove pallets from their orders so they can be pooled with other clients orders.

Comment: If time and speed is not a concern, you can use brute force algorithm, but if so you can always try a binary search.